# Is "PHP and MySQL Web Development, 4th ed." an outdated book to learn from?

Tags: learning, php, books, mysql

I want to get into web stuff, and thought of going with PHP+MySQL. I have experience in C#, C++, desktop graphics, but no web stuff besides HTML, CSS which I started learning 2 months ago.

On SO PHP-book question, the highest rated book is "PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice". However, I'm not sure if it's a book to start PHP with... or is it? Most of the books mentioned in that SO question seem to be for those who already know PHP.

I considered "PHP & MySQL Web Development, 4th Ed.", but someone mentioned that "it uses the mysql_* functions which are almost deprecated."

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590599098) is an excellent book, but you are correct in assuming is not for begginers. It's main objective is to help you understand design patterns in PHP.

[PHP & MySQL Web Development, 4th Ed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672329166). is a little bit outdated, it's not just the use of mysql_* functions, but that alone is enough.

Two beginner oriented books that focus on PHP 5.3 are:

- [Beginning PHP and MySQL: From Novice to Professional](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430231149)
- [Beginning PHP 5.3 (Wrox Programmer to Programmer)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470413964)

As for online resources:

- The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) is the authoritative source on all things PHP. Just ignore user comments, they are usually crap. There are some true gems in the comments, but as a beginner it won't be easy to identify them, so just ignore them.
- [PHP - The right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) is a well written introduction to the language.
- [phpmaster.com](http://phpmaster.com/) articles are (usually) extremely well written and very thorough. If they feel a bit too much, don't worry they have a [beginners section](http://phpmaster.com/category/php-tutorials/beginner/).

Comment: The manual? I've seen that said many times online, but I guess I'd like an intro to MySQL, db stuff too... that first book you linked seems alright

Comment: How is the "Head First PHP & MySql" book compared to the ones you posted? Is that outdated as well?

Comment: @ForeverLearnNeverMaster [Amazon says](http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-MySQL-Lynn-Beighley/dp/0596006306) it was published in 2008 so it's probably not so up to date. The [book site says](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfphp/) it supports PHP 6, but back then that was the name for the proposal that became version 5.3, and proposals tend to change a lot so some of the book's information may be irrelevant. Regardless, the *Head First* series is a very well written series and if you have access to the book, go for it. But if you don't and need to buy one you should choose a more recent one.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll just get the Novice to Pro book.

Comment: PHP Objects, Patterns and Practice might not be an introductory text, but it doesn't start at too high a level (considering that the Objects section is essentially a rewrite of that part of the PHP manual).